# Auto generate string array with suffix at compile time

Tags: c

I would like to generate an array of strings at compile time with two inputs - a known string and a number. For example, `hello` and `2` would generate at compile time:

```
#define SAMPLE_STRING "hello"
#define SAMPLE_NUM 2
```

Now here I suppose a macro would take these values and generate the following:

```
static const char sample[5][10] = {
"hello0",
"hello1",
"hello2"
};
```

I'd say the limit on the integer would be three digits at most. I guess I could use C macros to do this, but I'm not super familiar with them and I don't want to use any string functions at run time.

Comment: @RohanBari string and int values are known at compile time

Comment: use python, or write special program to generate .c or .h file. Not possible compile time

Comment: The C preprocessor doesn't support any sort of loops or recursion (unless you really severely abuse `#include`) so as @0___________ says, this has to be done by an external script.

Comment: Do you mean `"hello0","hello1","hello2"`  instead of `"hello0","hello2","hello3"`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri yes, typo. will edit.

Comment: You got the  answer: it is not possible

Comment: @0___________ indeed. thanks

Comment: See [99 bottles of beer in C preprocessor](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/99_bottles_of_beer#A_preprocessor_solution)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be so drastic, no need to go to Python, [P99](https://gitlab.inria.fr/gustedt/p99) allows you to do this while staying in the C environment, check the [P99 accessors](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/p99/p99-html/group__statement__lists_ga44356c23b76dc02e22487ba2f532dc39.html#ga44356c23b76dc02e22487ba2f532dc39)

Comment: @DavidRanieri it is good for the contest but not in normal sane programming.